# How to get the default item from solr collapse

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solrnet, solr4j

I am doing collapse on itemId like - `{!collapse field=itemId nullPolicy=expand}` . Its working as expected . So when it is doing the collpase it is showing me one result for itemID -123 that is fine , but in my dataset I have a field called defaultItemID which can be Y or N , and there will be only one defaultItemID:Y per itemID

Example - if I have a itemID - 123, and there are 20 results for itemID- 123 ,and out of those 20 records there will be only one item whose defaultItemID will be Y)

I want solr to return the the record where defaultItemID is Y , when doing the collapse , Is there anyway I can modify my collapse to do that . I tried sort but it was sorting the resut which were coming on exapanded.

Comment: Did you use `sort` as a parameter to the collapse localparam or as a global sort? I didn't think using it as a localparam (`{!collapse field=itemId nullPolicy=expand sort=defaultItemID desc}` would affect the global order. There is also a separate `expand.sort` parameter you can use to order the expanded documents if they are affected.

Comment: @MatsLindh no luck . I tried this before also , it is not displaying the item where defaultItemID  is Y . I tried asc and desc both